# How to pass a variable's pointer?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
GLint framebuffer_handle = 0;

void glGetIntegerv(GLenum pname,  GLint * data){ ... }

glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, *framebuffer_handle);
```

The last line reports an error:

> indirection requires pointer operand ('GLint' (aka 'int') invalid)

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Replace it with `glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &framebuffer_handle);`

Comment: `*` turns a pointer into a reference, but `&` turns a reference into a pointer (more or less, I'm simplifying hugely).

Comment: This is not an issue of passing a pointer to a function, so neither of the referenced duplicate questions were appropriate. I reopened this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`framebuffer_handle` is not a pointer, so you can't dereferenced it with the `*` operator. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

`glGetIntegerv()` wants a pointer to a `GLint`.  A pointer holds a memory address. You need to use the `&` operator to get the address of (ie, a pointer to) the `framebuffer_handle` variable, eg:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &framebuffer_handle);
```